# Creating a constantly shifting list in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, I've got a list of 10 items and I want to make Item 1 move to a random position in the list once a second.

Unfortunately, I can only get it to move once, and then it stays put despite the data-position number continuing to update every second.

```js
setInterval(function randomNumber() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    $('.listitems #1').attr( 'data-position', x);
}, 1000);

setInterval(function Sort() {
    $(".listitems li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.listitems');
    function sort_li(a, b){
        return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;    
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listitems">
     <li id="1" data-position="1">Item 1</li>
     <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
     <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
     <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
     <li data-position="5">Item 5</li>
     <li data-position="6">Item 6</li>
     <li data-position="7">Item 7</li>
     <li data-position="8">Item 8</li>
     <li data-position="9">Item 9</li>
     <li data-position="10">Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Hopefully I did a decent job explaining what I mean, but feel free to ask questions. Thank you in advance

Comment: Quick Note: You can simply do anonymous function call in setInterval argument

Comment: If you make a jsfiddle I would be happy to help

Comment: @Chris: There's a runnable demo right there in the question. If you want something else, everything is there for you to make it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gtsfuati2/drd30n0e/

Comment: @squint I didn't notice that the demo worked. 90% of the time it doesn't so I am in the habit of not clicking run

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, I hear that.

Answer (score 1):

`.data()` puts the data into the jQuery data store, but you're then updating the `.attr()`. So when you go to get the `.data()` again, it gets it from the store instead of from the attribute.

The solution is to update the `.data()` with the new random number.

```js
setInterval(function randomNumber() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    $('.listitems #1').data( 'position', x);
}, 1000);

setInterval(function Sort() {
    $(".listitems li").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.listitems');
    function sort_li(a, b){
        return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;    
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listitems">
     <li id="1" data-position="1">Item 1</li>
     <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
     <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
     <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
     <li data-position="5">Item 5</li>
     <li data-position="6">Item 6</li>
     <li data-position="7">Item 7</li>
     <li data-position="8">Item 8</li>
     <li data-position="9">Item 9</li>
     <li data-position="10">Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

---

And here's a non-jQuery solution:

```js
var par = document.querySelector(".listitems")
,   all = Array.from(par.querySelectorAll("li"));

setInterval(function randomNumber() {
    par.querySelector("#one").dataset.position = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    all.sort((a, b) => b.dataset.position < a.dataset.position ? 1 : -1 )
       .forEach(li => par.appendChild(li)); 
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listitems">
     <li id="one" data-position="1">Item 1</li>
     <li data-position="2">Item 2</li>
     <li data-position="3">Item 3</li>
     <li data-position="4">Item 4</li>
     <li data-position="5">Item 5</li>
     <li data-position="6">Item 6</li>
     <li data-position="7">Item 7</li>
     <li data-position="8">Item 8</li>
     <li data-position="9">Item 9</li>
     <li data-position="10">Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're welcome. And FYI, I'd probably use a single `setInterval` instead of two. Seems like every time a new random number is generated, you want to update the list, so just one would seem to be simpler. Plus the two can get out of sync.